# After an employee has been terminated, how long should you wait before taking away their access to company email?

Tags: email, termination, employment

Should I email them a notice period like I will take away your access to company email in 5 days so please back up your stuff or should I just take it away?

Comment: Depends a bit on if they quit themselves/were dismissed and if they are leaving on good terms.

Comment: What country is it?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: yeah, the question really only makes sense if the OP is a small business owner.

Comment: What exactly would they need to back up from their work email that you're willing to give them 5 days to do so?

Comment: Terminated? As in fired for cause? Do you really want them to be able to send stuff from p*ssedoff@company.com?

Comment: @jmoreno or, a startup.

Comment: If you revoke it immediately or a bit earlier, what damage could be done that cannot be fixed by granting access again if (against all odds) a valid need comes up afterwards?

Comment: Why are their email working after their last day at the company.  Even the DOD is able to delete an email of an employee of 31 years happened the day after the employees last day.

Answer (score 58):

Just like a company ID card or company provided laptop or access to office space - official email ID is also one of the resource provided to the employee for official use. Once the employment ends, the email ID should no longer be valid, and/or accessible to the individual. There's no reason to treat this separately. Any information exchange to/from the ID after end of employment could be illegal.

- Access (and validity) of the email ID should terminate by the end of last day of employment, for the case where separation is on mutual understanding and on good terms.
- In case of a "termination" (as in getting fired with immediate effect), the access should be revoked during (or even before, as situation demands) announcement of the news. When the news in communicated in a in-person meting, majority of the cases the physical access card, keys and other physical belongings are collected (taken away) and the (ex)-employee is escorted out of the office premises. At that point of time, they could/need not use the email for any productive / positive reason, so don't overthink it.

Comment: Not the end of the day, but as soon as they are "out the door"...

Comment: @SolarMike Which is usually end of the day. In exceptional scenario, exceptions measures are warranted, of course, where resources / access can be revoked even before they are out of the door.. :)

Comment: Sacked at 09.00 means out, not waiting around the place of work...

Comment: @SolarMike I kind of implied the same, but clarified answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: This has been the standard practice I've seen.
Typically, the email account remains valid and IT just changes the password, so that the person can no longer access it but any work-related email addressed to the person can be forwarded to the person's supervisor or successor for a few weeks / months to ease the transition. This also helps with work-related password recovery.
If the email account is simply closed right away, people writing to the person will get a bounce message, and then won't know who to write to instead.

Comment: May I ask what does "premise" mean in "*... escorted out of the office **premise***"? I don't quite get how the word carries its meaning.

Comment: @iBug probably "premises" is meant there and it means "place" or "space" here. Probably "out of the building" would be nearly the same in most cases. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/premises

Answer (score 35):

When the employment ends on good terms: On their last work day, so they can still use email to organize the handover to their successors.

When the employment ends on bad terms: While you tell them they are being fired, so they can not use email for any stupid retaliatory actions.

They should not have a reason to "back up their stuff" because company email should not be used for personal reasons, and all the company email should be backed up on the company server. So when a successor needs to look at it, they should be able to.

Comment: I took "back up your stuff" to mean that the employee is being asked to ensure that all company related work on the laptop is backed up on a company server (or handed over to someone else), because once the laptop is handed in IT will wipe it.

Comment: @PeterM: In all companies I worked at, IT took a backup of the terminated employee's computers, so no need for the ex-employee to do anything.

Comment: On another note -- depending on legislation and/or company policy, it might be straight-out illegal for one employee to look at another employee's emails, even if the latter has been let go.

Comment: 'company email should not be used for personal reasons'  Most organisations for which I've worked have had codified and published policies explicitly allowing personal use of organisational e-mail accounts, with boilerplate exceptions for unlawful/offensive/pornographic communications.  (I also note that I still occasionally receive e-mails on my account with an employer I left 16 years ago; but then, there are still occasional loose ends to tie up from that job, so there is a legitimate business reason of sorts for it...)

Comment: I've never worked for a company that didn't explicitly require in codified policies that work emails _not_ be used for personal reasons.  Work laptops and such could be used, sure, with the mentioned caveats -- but only because no one was lugging personal computers into work.  Virtually everyone has their own email and switching between two accounts is as simple as Alt-Tab.  It's not just a bad idea to mix them, it's absolutely bizarre.

Comment: Sensitive emails to HR may count as work-related, but shouldn't be viewed by your successor.

Comment: @MatthewRead You might be pretty young then. Before personal emails were easy to get and everyone had them, it was quite common for people who had an email address at work to use that for everything, personal and business. I still get a trickle of personal email to an email address that was my work email address from 1998 to 2010.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously on the last day that the person is working (not employed, but actually working) for the company.

You can give two weeks notice and expect the employee to work for two weeks - they will need access to their email while they work.

You can give two weeks notice, but you fear sabotage and move the employee from the premises immediately - remove email access immediately.

Obviously use common sense - if HR sends them documents to their company email address and then you cut email access off, that's no good.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on job - but in every company I was in it was already revoked (together with all computer access) when you left the office where you where terminated.

Comment: As is so often the case, academia can be an exception to this, but then there are such things as honorary (i.e. not employed) academic positions, with email accounts

Answer (score 1):

Depends of what you mean by Terminated most people I know regard this as on the spot firing but I've heard others use this in terms of leave at the end of the day or a few weeks notice.

Regardless of these it should be when the employment ceases officially so if it's on the spot firing it would be immediate, end of the day firing then end of the day or 5 days firing then at the end of the 5 days. I've also seen companies remove access when someone is on Gardening leave as you don't want them sending out emails in the company name during that period.

This is a note for any current employees that keeping any personal stuff on a company laptop or registering personal stuff to a company email is wrong as access to this can be taken away at any point. I remember I spoke to a lady from the USA who was fired on the spot in a meeting and when she got back to her desk her MacBook was gone and she was escorted out the building after clearing her desk. She was signed into her personal email and bank website on that company MacBook and was didn't realise till she was outside the building. This caused her a bit of stress so try to keep any logged in accounts to a minimal on company equipment.

Answer (score -3):

> Should I email them a notice period like I will take away your access to company email in 5 days so please back up your stuff or should I just take it away?

Just take it away, usually it's best to do it immediately upon termination.

Comment: Given the presence of other answers, it would be more helpful if you could add descriptions and explanations to your answer. Otherwise it may not be of much value.